# Sitemap for temporary pages

Tags: php, mysql, xml, sitemap

I have a website for football betting predictions. I get the available matches using curl from a bookmaker through xml. The specific bookmaker gives me the games for the following 3 days. All of games have IDs but after the 3 days the new games will get the same ids. For example the first three days will get the ids 100-655 the next three from 100-353 (less games available).

I store those games in a table so the user can see the games of the following games and i delete them when the new are up because that info is no use for anyone. Before i delete them i store them in another table after the games have ended so i can have a database with League tables for every league.

Next to each page i had a css popup window which had the following address www.mysite.com/history/id .So basicly it was looking at the table of the current games and from that it was taking the team names. Then it was looking to the other tables with the results of the games and the result was a page which had the recent form of the teams,history etc.

The problem is that the link www.mysite.com/history/600 for example one time will refer to the game Arsenal - Liverpool the next time to the game Manchester United - Newcastle and the next time will be a broken link.

I am thinking of two things atm.

1) My database/link stracture is wrong. If thats the case how can i solve it?

2) If it's not wrong how can i create a correct sitemap for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a unique ID for each game, irrespective of time. Persistent URLs are one of the tenets of the WWW.

You could achieve this by using an auto-increment key in your DB, and using this in the URL.

As for the sitemap, Just display a `410 Gone` page (and header) for each expired page.

Comment: So you are telling me that the link stracture i have atm is wrong .Although the user will never see those "broken" links because when the new games are available will be hided the problem is they will appear in search engines right?

Comment: Once a resource is published on the web, it is never removed. There's the google cache, the wayback machine etc. Your site will stop linking to these pages, but you need to handle the possibility of someone getting to the page another way.